# Flex corrupts buffer after yypop_buffer_state()

Tags: c, flex-lexer

I am trying to implement a loop of some sort by rescanning the loop body for n time. Here is the code for the lexer and the parser.

Lexer:

```
%option noyywrap
%{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "parser.tab.h"

int stackPtr = 0;
%}


%%

"for"                   { return FOR; }
"do"                    { return DO; }
"{"[^}]*"}"             {
                            yytext[yyleng - 1] = 0;
                            yylval.s = strdup(yytext+1); 
                            return LOOP;
                        }

[a-zA-Z]+               { yylval.s = strdup(yytext); return WORD; }
[0-9]+                  {
                            yylval.d = atoi(yytext);
                            return NUMBER;
                        }

<<EOF>>                 { 
                            if (stackPtr) {
                                yypop_buffer_state();
                                stackPtr--;
                            }
                        }

"\n"                    { return EOL; }
[ \t]
.                       { abort(); }

%%

void do_loop(int n, char *c) {
    char s[256];
    int len = sprintf(s, "\n%s", c);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        yypush_buffer_state(yy_scan_bytes(s, len));
        stackPtr++;
    }
}
```

Parser:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>

extern void do_loop(int, char*);
extern int yylex(void);
void yyerror(char *);
%}

%token FOR DO EOL
%token <s> LOOP WORD
%token <d> NUMBER

%union {
    char *s;
    int d;
}

%%

program: stmt
       | program EOL stmt
;

stmt:
    | string { printf("\n"); }
    | FOR NUMBER DO LOOP
        {
            do_loop($2, $4);
        }
;

string: WORD        { printf("%s ", $1); }
      | string WORD { printf("%s ", $2); }
;

%%

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    yyparse();
}

void yyerror(char *s)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "error: %s\n", s);
}
```

It works for the first time but after `yypop_buffer_state()` it is aborted due to due to the rule `. { abort(); }`. I tried debugging it with gdb and found out the yytext become random value. I am having a hard time finding out when did the buffer turns to gibberish but I only know that it happens after `yypop_buffer_state()` doesn't really know how to fix it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30128729/1566221

Comment: I think the question whose answer I linked above is a duplicate. Do you agree? In any event, this is not the way to implement loops for a variety of reasons, starting with the fact that you cannot recognise a loop body with a regex. (You need to take into account nested braces, as well as braces which happen to be inside strings and comments.) You should build an AST. Then there is no need to reoeat the parse.

Comment: I originally planned on implementing AST following the book Flex and Bison by John Levine but I got completely lost when it it explained loops and function call. BTW, I did'nt realize that `yy_scan_buffer` actually call `yy_switch_buffer` so by the time I pushed the string the original buffer is already lost. Also thank for the feedback.